# How to send data using Python-Zeroconf

Tags: python, zeroconf

I saw a [tutorial on Python-Zeroconf](https://pypi.org/project/zeroconf/).

The tutorial showed how to create a Python-Zeroconf listener so I know how to receive data.

This is below.

```
from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, Zeroconf

class MyListener:

    def remove_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        print("Service %s removed" % (name,))

    def add_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        info = zeroconf.get_service_info(type, name)
        print("Service %s added, service info: %s" % (name, info))


zeroconf = Zeroconf()
listener = MyListener()
browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_http._tcp.local.", listener)
try:
    input("Press enter to exit...\n\n")
finally:
    zeroconf.close()
```

But it didn't seem to write how to send the data. Is it possible to send data using Python-Zeroconf? How can I send it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeroconf is about letting a client find a service and which port to connect to, not the actual data transmission.
There are tutorials on the net about creating simple clients and servers in python.
Here is one [Python socket programming](https://www.journaldev.com/15906/python-socket-programming-server-client).